# why do we use smell and not smells in this particular phrase?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> I bought an air freshener to make my room smell pleasant

Why do you use *smell* not *smells*

Comment: 'smell' is being used as a verb there.

Comment: yeah i know ,  but the room is  singular

Comment: The answers are right -- 'make' is a ^raising* verb, so 'my room' is *raised* from subject of 'smell' to object of 'make', and 'smell' is infinite (only the main verb 'make' gets tense and agreement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the room is not the subject of that verb.

> I bought some perfume to make me smell pleasant

Here you can see that "me" (not "I"!) is not a subject. Therefore, the verb does not get conjugated. So this verb form actually is the infinitive.

Comment: i didn't get you ! thanks Any way @stoneyb

Answer (score 5):

When "make" is used in the *causative* sense (="cause or compel [X to happen]") it takes an *unmarked infinitival clause* as its complement: that is, a clause headed by a verb in its infinitive form, without the marker *to*:

> His mother made him <s>to</s> **clean** up his room.
>   Air freshener makes the room <s>to</s> **smell** pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

After 'make', meaning cause, we use the 'base' or infinitive version of a verb. Make my car go (not goes) faster.

> make verb (CAUSE)
>   ​
>   B1 [ T ] to cause something: The kids made a real mess in the kitchen.
>   The bullet made a hole right through his chest.
>
> **[ + infinitive without to ]** The wind is making my eyes water. What made you change your mind?
>   Just seeing Woody Allen's face is enough to make me laugh. The
>   photograph makes me look about 80!

[Make (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make)